# I am trying to convert Java code to scala

Tags: scala, selenium-chromedriver, fluentwait

I want to use fluent wait with selenium in scala. However I am not able to convert the below code into Scala. Please help me out.

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
        .withTimeout(30, SECONDS)
        .pollingEvery(5, SECONDS)
        .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

WebElement foo = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() 
{
  public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
  return driver.findElement(By.id("foo"));
}
});
```

When I use it in Scala, I get

@BrianMcCutchon - Hi. When I use this code in Scala, it gets converted to the following,

```
val wait = new FluentWait[WebDriver](driver).withTimeout(30, SECONDS).pollingEvery(5, SECONDS).ignoring(classOf[Nothing])

  val foo = wait.until(new Nothing() {
    def apply(driver: WebDriver): WebElement = driver.findElement(By.id("foo"))
  })
```

In this code, val wait is not resolved. Moreover, Nothing seems meaningless

Comment: Hi Anand, can you show what you've tried so far and where specifically you're having problems?

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon - Hi. Please see my updated question.

Answer (score 1):

This code should be written with lambdas in both Java (8 and later) and Scala (2.12 to interoperate with Java interface `Function`) unless you have a specific reason not to.

Java:

```
WebElement foo = wait.until(driver -> driver.findElement(By.id("foo")));
```

Scala:

```
val foo = wait.until(_.findElement(By.id("foo")))
```

or

```
val foo = wait.until(driver => driver.findElement(By.id("foo")))
```

Also, `wait` should have `ignoring(classOf[NoSuchElementException])`, not `Nothing`.

Comment: But this solution does not use Fluent Wait

Comment: Yes, it does. It's still the same `until` method on `FluentWait`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not talking about that Selenium's FluentWait here. For a generic fluent api in Java, it should have a default value, shouldn't it? In that case, the named parameter in Scala looks better to me. For example,

```scala
new FluentWait(timeout = 30.seconds, polling = 5.seconds)
```

the `ignoring` argument is ignored and will get the default value of `classOf[NoSuchElementException]`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the conversion:

### Converting "wait"

The Java and Scala are pretty similiar here. Just note that:

1. Scala uses `[]` for generics instead of Java's `<>`.
2. Scala's version of `SomeClass.class` is `classOf[SomeClass]`.

**Java:**

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
    .withTimeout(30, SECONDS)
    .pollingEvery(5, SECONDS)
    .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
```

**Scala:**

```
val wait = new FluentWait[WebDriver](driver)
    .withTimeout(30, SECONDS)
    .pollingEvery(5, SECONDS)
    .ignoring(classOf[NoSuchElementException])
```

### Converting "foo"

This is a good place to illustrate the similarity between functional-style Java and Scala I'm translating your example to a functional-style in Java and using `var` which was introduced in Java 10. The Scala version is very, very similar to this style.

**Your Java:**

```
WebElement foo = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
  public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
    return driver.findElement(By.id("foo"));
  }
});
```

**Function-style Java w/ local type inference (JDK 10+):**

```
var foo = wait.until(driver -> driver.findElement(By.id("foo")));
```

**Scala:**

```
val foo = wait.until(driver => driver.findElement(By.id("foo")))
```

In Scala `_` can be used instead of an explicit parameter name in the function call. This is a style-choice, but you could also write the above Scala code as:

```
val foo = wait.until(_.findElement(By.id("foo")))
```